# Nasdaq Composite Futures?

Tags: futures, nasdaq

When the financial press talks about Nasdaq futures, they are talking about Nasdaq 100 Futures. How come they do not use the Nasdaq Composite Futures?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst CME Group does have  E-mini NASDAQ Composite Futures listed, nobody trades them.  The volume is all in the E-mini Nasdaq 100 futures.

You can see this volume here:
http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/products/#pageNumber=1&sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&group=4&page=1

In addition, sophisticated trading houses performing arbitrage trades against the underlying index and its constituents.  Trading around 100 stocks is far simpler with less slippage than the thousands of stocks in the Composite index.